# Robot awt does not work properly with the JNativeHook library

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I'm trying to create an auto clicker using the JNativeHook library to track the click of a button on the desktop. Then I save the received coordinates in Map and by means of Robot awt I try to move the cursor to the set coordinates, but for some reason it moves incorrectly. If I press at the beginning of the screen (0, 0), the coordinates are the same and the further I move the mouse, the greater the difference in coordinates. Maybe someone knows the solution to correct this error with coordinates?